# Adding export utf8 to /etc/profile not working

Tags: bash, debian, locale, .bash-profile

Trying to set the locale in debian:stretch to utf8. I build a docker image which I then use. Apart of my Dockerfile:

```
# Set locale
RUN sed --in-place '/en_US.UTF-8/s/^# //' /etc/locale.gen && \
    locale-gen && \
    # Set system locale (add line)
    echo "export LANG=en_US.UTF-8" >> /etc/profile && \
    # Set system timezone (add line)
    echo "export TZ=UTC" >> /etc/profile
```

Gitlab job which uses the image I built:

```
$ cat /etc/profile
# /etc/profile: system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell (sh(1))
# and Bourne compatible shells (bash(1), ksh(1), ash(1), ...).

if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
  PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
else
  PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games"
fi
export PATH

if [ "${PS1-}" ]; then
  if [ "${BASH-}" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export TZ=UTC
$ locale
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

I don't understand why it's not being changed. It doesn't seem to read the `/etc/profile` file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cite the `bash(1)` manual page:

> When  bash  is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the `--login` option, it first reads and
>   executes commands from the file `/etc/profile`, if that file exists.
>   After  reading  that file,  it  looks  for  `~/.bash_profile`,
>   `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile`, in that order, and reads and
>   executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The
>   `--noprofile` option may be used when the  shell is started to inhibit
>   this behavior.
>
> <…>
>
> When an interactive shell that is not a login shell is  started,  bash
>   reads  and  executes  commands  from `/etc/bash.bashrc`  and 
>   `~/.bashrc`,  if  these files exist.  This may be inhibited by using
>   the `--norc` option. The `--rcfile` file option will force bash to
>   read and execute commands from file instead of  `/etc/bash.bashrc` and
>   `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: All in all, I don't really understand why you need to mess with the shell's startup script as there exists [the standard approach to configuring the system-wide locale on Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Locale).